# Show HTML <audio> volume slider

Tags: html

I am writing a html code to play some audio files for my organization.

On chrome, at least (im not sure about other browsers) the  tag has a volume slider, but to use it you have to click on the volume button:

```html
<audio controls=""> <source src="https://www.bensound.com/royalty-free-music?download=goinghigher"></audio>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to make the volume slider, always available to change

Thanks
      -Fred

Comment: On my system, the volume functional is visible when the url is loaded.

Comment: What Browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Google chrome